# PHP createimage function doesn't work

Tags: php, html, image-uploading

I have a couple of functions in my PHP file to handle the upload of images.
3 resize functions work fine, but one doesn't: **watermark_image**. The code is exactly the same as the code of the other resize-and-watermark functions, but it only stores the SRC in my database but not the image file itself in the directory.
I have tried changing all the variable names (because like I said, they're exactly the same but within a different method), but that didn't work.

What am I missing here?

**To be clear, the issue is with saving the new, resized image in the directory, not with placing the watermark on the image.**

*the resize_big function is exactly the same as the watermark_image function, aside from the size of the image. The watermark is 135 × 38px.*

**Form:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="background-color:white; margin-top:100px;">
    <div>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="paard" selected>Paarden</option>
        <option value="hond">Honden</option>
        <option value="mens">Mensen</option>
        <option value="eigen">Eigen werk</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="file"/><Br/>

    Model: <input type="text" name="model" id="model"/>
    <br/>

    <label class="radio">Portfoliomateriaal</label>
    <input type="radio" name="folio" value="TRUE" /> <span>Ja</span>
    <input type="radio" name="folio" value="FALSE" checked /> <span>Nee</span><p>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP function in top of upload page:**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

include "include/resize.php";
include "include/config.php";

if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    // Delete hele directory: array_map('unlink', glob("some/dir/*.txt"));  && Leeg tabel SQL: DELETE FROM table_name;or DELETE * FROM table_name; OF "TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;"
    $deleteID = $_GET['delete'];
    echo "<p style='color:white;'>".$deleteID."</p>";

    $select = "SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id=".$deleteID;
    $results = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_count=mysql_num_rows($results);
    while ($images = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        unlink($images['orig']);
        unlink($images['web']);
        unlink($prev = $images['prev']);
        unlink($thumb = $images['thumb']);
    }


    $deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM photo WHERE id=".$deleteID;
    mysql_query($deleteSQL) or die(mysql_error());
}


$file_dest = "photos/orig/";
$thumb_dest = "photos/thumb/";
$web_dest = "photos/web/";
$prev_dest = "photos/preview/";
//$dir = 'uploads/foto/'.$_POST['cat'].'/';

if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])){

    $files = $_FILES['files'];

    $uploaded = array();
    $bestanden = array();
    $failed = array();

    $allowedExt = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');

    foreach($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
        $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
        $file_error = $files['error'][$position];
        $file_cat = $_POST['category'];
        $file_folio = $_POST['folio'];
        $file_model = ucfirst($_POST['model']);
        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        if(in_array($file_ext, $allowedExt)){

            if($file_error == 0){

                if($file_size <= 32000000){

                    $file_name_new = uniqid('', true)."_".$file_name;
                    $path_web = $web_dest.$file_name_new;
                    $path_thumb = $thumb_dest.$file_name_new;
                    $path_prev = $prev_dest.$file_name_new;

                    list($file_width, $file_height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

                    //Wat is het grootste?
                    if($file_width > $file_height){
                        $largest = $file_width;
                    }else if($file_height > $file_width){
                        $largest = $file_height;
                    }else if($file_height = $file_width){
                        $largest = $file_height;
                    }

                    if($largest <= 800){
                        //echo "image is already web-sized";
                        $file_move = $web_dest.$file_name_new;
                        $path_orig = "";
                    }else{
                        $file_move = $file_dest.$file_name_new;
                        $path_orig = $file_move;
                        watermark_image($file_move, $path_web);
                    }

                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_move)){
                        $uploaded[$position]['naam'] = $file_name;
                        $uploaded[$position]['pad'] = $file_move;
                        if($largest > 1080){
                            resize_big($file_move, $file_move);
                        }
                        resize_image($file_move, $path_prev);
                        create_thumbnail($file_move, $path_thumb, 75, 75);

                        $query = "INSERT INTO photo (name, cat, orig, web, prev, thumb, folio) VALUES ('$file_model', '$file_cat', '$path_orig', '$path_web', '$path_prev', '$path_thumb', '$file_folio')";
                        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                        //mysql_close();
                    }else{
                        $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] failed to upload.";
                    }
                }else{
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] is too large.";
                }

            }else{
                $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] errored with code {$file_error}";
            }

        }else{
            $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] file extension '{$file_ext}' is not allowed.";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($uploaded)){
        /*
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($uploaded);
        echo "</pre>";
        */
    }

    if(!empty($failed)){
        print_r($failed);
    }

    header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);die;

    //end foreach function
}else{
    echo "No files were added.";
}

?>
```

**PHP file that contains the resize functions:**

```
<?php
//WATERMERK and RESIZE function

    //Watermark function
    function watermark_image($file, $destination){

        //Get watermark
        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/watermerk.png');

        //Max width and height of resized image
        $width = 800;
        $height = 800;

        //Type and size file
        $source = getimagesize($file);  

        //Get part of the array, e.g. image/jpeg
        $source_mime = $source['mime']; 


        //Check which file, then make image

        if($source_mime == 'image/png'){
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            }else if($source_mime == 'image/jpeg'){
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            } else if($source_mime == 'image/gif'){
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            }

        //New dimensions
        list($file_width, $file_height) = getimagesize($file);

        $file_ratio = $file_width/$file_height;

        if ($width/$height > $file_ratio) {
            $width = $height*$file_ratio;
            } else {
             $height = $width/$file_ratio;
            }

        // Resample
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);

        //Put size of picture in variable
        $file_x = imagesx($new_image);
        $file_y = imagesy($new_image);

        //Size watermark
        $logo_x = imagesx($watermark);
        $logo_y = imagesy($watermark);

        //Place of watermark
        $pos_x = 1;
        $pos_y = $file_y - $logo_y + 1;


        //Put watermark on image
        imagecopy($new_image, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $logo_x, $logo_y);
        imagepng($new_image, $destination);
        //echo $destination;    

        //Destroy temporary files
        imagedestroy($new_image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($watermark);   

    }

/*==============================================================================*/
//PREV RESIZE FUNCTIE

    function resize_image($file, $destination){

        //Get watermark
        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/copy.png');

        //max. width and height of resized image.
        $width = 400;
        $height = 400;

        //Type and size of file
        $source = getimagesize($file);  

        //Get part of array, e.g. image/jpeg
        $source_mime = $source['mime']; 


        //Check which file, then make image

        if($source_mime == 'image/png'){
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            }else if($source_mime == 'image/jpeg'){
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            } else if($source_mime == 'image/gif'){
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            }

        //Set new dimensions
        list($file_width, $file_height) = getimagesize($file);

        $file_ratio = $file_width/$file_height;

        if ($width/$height > $file_ratio) {
            $width = $height*$file_ratio;
            } else {
             $height = $width/$file_ratio;
            }

        // Resample
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);

        //Put size of image in variable
        $file_x = imagesx($new_image);
        $file_y = imagesy($new_image);

        //Size of watermark
        $logo_x = imagesx($watermark);
        $logo_y = imagesy($watermark);

        //Place of watermark
        $pos_x = ($file_x - $logo_x)/2;
        $pos_y = ($file_y - $logo_y)/2;


        //Put watermark on image
        imagecopy($new_image, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $logo_x, $logo_y);
        imagepng($new_image, $destination);
        //echo $destination;    

        //Destroy temporary files
        imagedestroy($new_image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($watermark);   

    }

/*==============================================================================*/
//BIG RESIZE FUNCTION


    function resize_big($file, $destination){

        //Watermark ophalen in php
        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/watermerk.png');

        //De maximum breedte en hoogte van de geresizede foto.
        $width = 1920;
        $height = 1080;

        //Type en grootte van het bestand ophalen
        $source = getimagesize($file);  

        //Gedeelte van het array ophalen, bijv image/jpeg
        $source_mime = $source['mime']; 


        //Controleren welk type het bestand is, dan hiervoor een plaatje aanmaken

        if($source_mime == 'image/png'){
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            }else if($source_mime == 'image/jpeg'){
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            } else if($source_mime == 'image/gif'){
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            }

        //Nieuwe afmetingen bepalen
        list($file_width, $file_height) = getimagesize($file);

        $file_ratio = $file_width/$file_height;

        if ($width/$height > $file_ratio) {
            $width = $height*$file_ratio;
            } else {
             $height = $width/$file_ratio;
            }

        // Resample
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);

        //Grootte van de foto in een variabele stoppen
        $file_x = imagesx($new_image);
        $file_y = imagesy($new_image);

        //Grootte van het watermerk bepalen
        $logo_x = imagesx($watermark);
        $logo_y = imagesy($watermark);

        //Plaats van het watermerk bepalen
        $pos_x = 1;
        $pos_y = $file_y - $logo_y + 1;


        //Watermerk erop plaatsen.
        //Eerst het bronbestand, dan het watermerk, dan de positie (1p px van de top, 10 px van links), dan waar het bronbestand begint, dan de grootte van het watermerk definieren.
        imagecopy($new_image, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $logo_x, $logo_y);
        imagepng($new_image, $destination);
        //echo $destination;    

        //Tijdelijke bestanden vernietigen
        imagedestroy($new_image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($watermark);   

    }


/*==============================================================================*/
//THUMBNAIL FUNCTION


        function create_thumbnail($path, $save, $width, $height){
            $info = getimagesize($path);
            $size = array($info[0], $info[1]);

        //Controleren welk type bestand het is
            if($info['mime'] == 'image/png'){
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($path);
            }else if($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
            }else if($info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($path);
            }else{
                return false;
            }


            //Thumbnail creeeren
            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            //Aspect ratio's
            $src_aspect = $size[0] / $size[1];
            $thumb_aspect = $width / $height;

            //Controleren of de foto horizontaal of verticaal is
            if($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){
                //Verticaal, dus boven en onder afcroppen

                //resize
                $scale = $width / $size[0];
                $new_size = array($width, $width / $src_aspect);
                //Croppen
                $src_pos = array(0, ($size[1] * $scale - $height) / $scale / 2);

            }else if($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){
                //Horizontaal, dus links en rechts afcroppen

                //resize
                $scale = $height / $size[1];
                $new_size = array($height * $src_aspect, $height);
                //croppen
                $src_pos = array(($size[0] * $scale - $width) / $scale / 2, 0);
            }else{
                //Vierkant

                //resize
                $new_size = array($width, $height);
                //croppen
                $src_pos = array(0, 0);
            }

            //fouten opvangen
            $new_size[0] = max($new_size[0], 1);
            $new_size[1] = max($new_size[1], 1);

            //Geresizede foto op de thumbnail plakken.
            //Gemaakte thumbnail, originele plaatje, begint linksbovenin, locatie waar je van wil kopieren x y, nieuwe grootte van de foto (Geresized) x y, originele grootte van de foto
            imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);

            if($save == false){
                return imagepng($thumb);

            }else{
                //Saven
                return imagepng($thumb, $save);
            }
        }   

?>
```

Comment: Which of the functions is currently malfunctioning? And as a sidenote; try commenting your code in english instead of dutch. It makes a big difference when posting on SO ;)

Comment: @RichardBernards I'll translate, didn't think about it! watermark_image doesn't work

Comment: What are the dimensions of your watermark?

Comment: @RichardBernards 135 × 38px, but it's also used on the resize_big function, so the watermark can't be the issue. Can it?

Comment: Nope, but since I didnt know the dimensions, I couldn't be sure; if the dimensions of the watermark were between 800 and 1080, I knew where the problem was ;) I just noticed you have to different 'watermark'-images referenced (`copy.png` and `watermerk.png`), are they both the same dimensions and colorscheme? Try swapping them...

Comment: No, copy.png is a different one (one to display photos with a full-watermark on top, those dimensions are 248 × 30px, but that function works fine too).
And the image doesn't 'appear' in my directory thus is not saved correctly, I think the issue has to do with saving the image instead of the watermark :). (can't see the outputted image, so can't see if the watermark is placed on top, haha)

Comment: @RichardBernards Translated a bunch of comments :)